# SSRS - Still no local rendering of 2008 reports in the latest viewer?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer2008

I can't believe this - I just starting developing an SSRS report, using a SQL 2008 Report Server project in VS 2008. When I try to render the report in the VS 2008 ReportViewer control, I get this error

```
The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an 
invalid target namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'
which cannot be upgraded."
```

I understand the error, and it has been well-documented all over the web over the past year and a half or so, but can it be that there is still no way of viewing these reports in the latest ReportViewer control? In other words, all these announcements from last year that MS would release an updated ReportViewer control in Q1 of 2009 that can render SSRS 2008 reports were wrong? 
The only workaround is to install SQL Server 2005 RS? How have others solved this? Switch to VS 2010? Can I register the 2010 ReportViewer control with my VS2008 project, and is that going to solve the problem? So many questions, but no answers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is indeed the truth :-(

See Bill Vaughn's [Retraction: The ReportViewer Control Does NOT Support SQL Server 2008 RDL in Local Mode](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3766476/Retraction-The-ReportViewer-Control-Does-NOT-Support-SQL-Server-2008-RDL-in-Local-Mode.htm) for more details.

Hard to believe - but true :-( Let's hope it'll be better in Reporting Services for SQL Server 2010 - eerrghh... 2008 R2 :-)

Marc

Comment: What is so pathetic is not that MS screwed this up (they can't possibly have planned this "feature", even if they claim so), but that they have failed the provide any kind of guidance around the issue. I mean, there could be a blog post at least that clearly says that you must install VS2005 and SQL 2005 in parallel to the 2008 stack, and what editions, so that you have the minimal requirements that allow you to design SSRS reports that render in the 2008 control. Or they could explain that (if the reports don't have to get deployed to a report server) you can use the 2008 report designer.

Comment: And could further explain what kind of degradation or limitation you have to live with by doing that. This control is a mainstream product, after all, that is used by Fortune 500 companies.